# Get setter status in python

Tags: python, setter

I am looking to return a status when setting an instance variable. This return value will either indicate that the value was set or the value was invalid. For example:

```
class C():
    def __init__(self):
        self._attr = 1

    @property
    def attr(self):
        return self._attr

    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, val):
        if val < 10:
            self._attr = val
            return 'value set'
        else:
            return 'value must be < 10'

status = C().attr = 11 # should return failed
status = C().attr = 9 # should return worked
```

Adding return values to all my setters would be time-consuming and seems to be bad practice. Is there a better way to get a status from a setter?

The other solution I thought of was to write a "setSetter()" function that calls `attr = val` then checks if `attr == val` (which works like a status variable). However, it seems like there should be a better method.

Also, if there is a better way to structure the flow control so that attributes aren't set to invalid values I'm open to changing my strategy.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: I think this whole thing isn't very pythonic

Comment: No, you can't meaningfully `return` from a property setter, because in Python *assignment is not an expression*. Notice, for example, how `a = b = 2` (chained assignment) works, but `a = (b = 2)` is a syntax error (trying to treat `b = 2` as an expression). No matter what your implementation is, unless an exception is raised then `status = C().attr = 11` causes `status` to become equal to... `11`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard way to indicate failure in Python and/or prevent code from reaching an invalid state is to `raise` an exception to indicate you've encountered a situation where you can't continue execution.  This doesn't require you to modify the return type:

```
    @attr.setter
    def attr(self, val: int) -> None:
        if val < 10:
            self._attr = val
        else:
            raise ValueError('value must be < 10')
```

```
try:
    C().attr = 9  # works
    C().attr = 11 # raises ValueError and goes to nearest matching except
    C().attr = 13 # is never executed
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)      # prints 'value must be < 10'
```

Comment: You could improve slightly by making it a guard clause instead of an `else`

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking, raise an error. Setter aren't suppose to return anything. just set if valid, or raise

Comment: @wjandrea I agree with you, but this improvement seems to be a hard sell for a lot of people. The doctrine of single-exit lives on.

Comment: I don't want to get into a whole thing, but I think it's situational which is better.  Usually I prefer `if/else` if it's a single condition with two short blocks ("either this happens or this happens"), but will always use guard clauses if there are multiple conditions or if the exception is very short compared to the main body.  In this particular case having the `if` predicate match the error makes it a little easier to verify that the error message matches the condition; inverting it requires an extra second of consideration to confirm that one excludes the other.

Comment: There's also a principle at play of making diffs minimal; by preserving the original structure you make it easier for a reviewer (in this case the original author) to see that the basic original intent is preserved.  Obviously in some cases you have to completely refactor code to make it work, but all else being equal it's preferable to match the original style and structure to the extent possible while making improvements.  Oh dear, I said I wasn't going to get into a whole thing.

Comment: Raising an error would work but would stop the program (unless ```try/except``` is added, which seems like overkill). Is there a method without raising an error? I want to add functionality where the setter was called if the status be "failed."

Comment: If you're returning a status code as in your original example you'll need to check it in an `if/else`, which is exactly as much "overkill" in the calling code as a `try/except` -- in fact the `if` is more complicated if you have multiple statuses to check, since then you have to either check each one in its own block or `or` them all together, whereas you can handle many exceptions in a single `try`/`except` block if you want to; they're designed exactly this way in order to make it easier.

Comment: The first time people encounter exceptions they tend to regard them as something scary that "breaks" your program (probably because as a novice Python programmer seeing an exception means you messed something up, so there's a negative Pavlovian response to them that is acquired early).  In reality, they're a hugely useful way of communicating success/failure, because a process that requires lots of steps and/or nested scopes can easily interrupt itself without having to explicitly check an error status at each stage.  Using them where appropriate can make life much easier!

Comment: @Samwise fair I see your point. I think the best option would be to create a ```set()``` function that calls the setter inside of a ```try/except``` block. If an error is caught, then further functionality will occur. Does that sound like a good option?

Comment: Seems reasonable as long as you're sure the "further functionality" is the right thing to do in all cases.  In most cases it's better to raise to the caller so that they know that they passed in a bad value, and let them figure out how to correct course.  For example, if the caller got the value from user input, they can prompt the user to try again.  If the caller got the value from THEIR caller, they can just do nothing, and the exception raises automatically (this is where raising is REALLY useful).

Comment: @Samwise All good points about the guard clause, thanks for informing me! You're right, you'd have to make it `not val < 10` which is ugly, or `val >= 10` which could be confusing in the diff.